# Syntax Error:expected expression got end of script

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I Tried lot but can't solve this problem

**Here is my Code:**

```
<?php 

    while($crow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cres)) {                                  
      echo '
         <div class="item" onclick="window.open("'.$crow["c_link"].'");window.open("'.$crow["c_link"].'","_self")<img src="images/carousel/'.$crow["c_pic"].'" alt="'.$crow['c_nm'].'"></div>
      ';
  }
?>
```

**There is error Like this:**

[image: Syntax Error:expected expression got end of script]

I also tried another answer of this problem but it is not working for me.
can anybody please tell me how to solve this ?

Comment: This is a poorly written question, please see here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask how to write a clear concise question.

Comment: `onclick="window.open("'.$crow["c_link"].'");window.open("'.$crow["c_link"].'","_self")"` should probably be something like `onclick="window.open(\''.$crow["c_link"].'\',\'_self\');"` so vtc as a typo error.

Comment: This is almost surely a problem with mismatched quotes, but with your formatting it is difficult to tell. Try breaking it up instead of having 300 characters on one line?

Comment: step 1 - view the page source in the browser. step 2 - see how it differs from what you expected, step 3 - rectify your code, paying attention to escaping quotes when necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with mixed quotes and aprostrophes

```
onclick="window.open("
```

You open `onclick` attribute value with `"` character and then close the attribute just after `window.open(`. Instead of the second `"` use `\'` or IMO even better close PHP mode, print HTML code and open PHP mode only to print PHP values

```
while($crow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cres)) { 
    ?><div class="item" onclick="window.open('<?=$crow['c_link']?>'); window.open('<?=$crow['c_link']?>');"><img ... ></div><?php
}
?>
```

this way it's easier to not get confused by combination of JS and PHP quotes and apostrophes.